# How do I boot from a SD card with grub?

Tags: boot, grub, sd-card

I wanna boot from an SD card in my PC's internal SD card reader. Is it possible to boot from the SD card like from a Hard disk ? Is there a specific "command" or something like that? (e.g. `hd`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SD cards are NORMALLY addressed as  /dev/mmcblkXY   for ex.   /dev/mmcblkp1

Other than that   the usual grub install /update commands work fine

Comment: The number stands for what ?

Comment: the numbers stand for partitions    just  like /dev/sdXY would but using mmcblk instead